# struts date text tag is thread safe

Tags: multithreading, jsp, struts2, thread-safety

I am using following struts text tag in my jsp :

```
"expirationDate" : "<s:text name='date'><s:param name='value' value='#xyz'/></s:text>"
```

In my `package.properties` I have following entry

```
date = {0,date,yyyy-MM-dd}
```

I am facing some thread safety issue with above statement in jsp, when multiple request access this jsp some time data of other request comes as response for a request. I am feeling that above statement is not thread safe. I want to know what struts internally uses for date formatting, does it use simpledateformatter or whatever it uses does it thread safe? or I need to put isThreadSafe = false in jsp to handle it or is there any other way to handle it?

Comment: Where and how do you use `<s:text>` tag? What exactly is happening?

Comment: I am using <s:text> tag in jsp file to format the date field of a java object. I am observing that when multiple http calls are accessing same jsp response is being messed up, i.e. expiration date for some http request is coming as response of some another request. I feel that is happening because <s:text name='date'> is not thread safe, probably because internally it is using same instance of simple date formatter. Want to get opinion on this from experts ..