# How struts property tag works with date value?

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, struts-tags

I have a JSP page where i am getting a Date value from my action class. I am not able to understand how it is handled as:

```
<s:property value="#someDate"/>
```

gives me date

```
2/7/14
```

whereas

```
<s:property value="{#someDate}"/>
```

gives me Date as

```
[Wed Feb 7 00:00:00 IST 2014]
```

Can someone tell me how date value is actually handled here, as date is returned in different formats?

Comment: The property of `someDate` is which type .. ? I mean String or Date type

Comment: I dont know much .. I think  struts2 `<s:property>` tag evaluates the variable in valuestack by the notion that you have used to get the variable when you use `#` key is used to access the variables has been set by the `<s:set>` tag when you use that `{#someDate}` it will get the value as type of the variable that has been set by its setter. And when you use `#someDate` it normally searches the value stack by the name `someDate` and returns as `String` that format `2/7/14` is the real format that pushed to the `someDate` variable.. for more info check ognl documentation.

Comment: If I am wrong some one correct me . plz

Comment: Why are you using the property tag and not the <s:date ... /> tag? This tag is especially for date output handling.

Comment: ya, We can use  <s:date /> tag.. but i just want to know the reason of difference of results in the cases mentioned.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21607045/how-come-struts-property-tag-converts-java-util-date-in-m-d-yy-format

Comment: Thanks for the link... that helped me to understand :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Nice Question.

`<s:property value="{#someDate}"/>` is equal to `<s:property value="someDate.toString()"/`> or `${someDate}` where as `<s:property value="someDate"/>` is using built in type conversion of **xwork2** which **uses the SHORT format for the Locale associated with the current request for dates.**

See  [Built in Type Conversion Support](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/type-conversion.html#TypeConversion-BuiltinTypeConversionSupport)

```
value="{#someDate}" means value="someDate.toString()"
```

**it converts date to date.tosting() that is why you are getting  [Wed Feb 7 00:00:00 IST 2014]**

To handle date formats there is a special tag  in struts2

```
<s:date name="someDate" format="dd/MM/yyyy" />
```

Prints

```
17/04/2014
```

Also see

```
<s:date name="someDate" format="dd/MMM/yyyy" />
```

Prints

```
17/Apr/2014
```

Also there is attibute `nice="true"`

```
<s:date name="someDate" nice="true" />
```

Prints

```
 2 days ago
```